# View records by date added - not activity date/date received

Tags: civicontribute

Adding a bunch of contribution records with a variety of dates manually - I would like to see all the records I added today - what would be an easy way to do that? Last modified would be fine too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since i found the answer - I might as well answer it.

Turn on Detailed Logging at Adminisiter - System Settings - Misc

When thats done - go to reports, contact logging report (now available when logging is turned on) and view results - you can filter for contributions, who entered the contibution (altered by), and other options. Customize to your liking and save as a copy so you can easily access the customized report.

After time - this report can get pretty resource heavy - but it may be worth it to you - like it is for me.  Note: this will not work for past activities - only activities since detailed logging was turned on.

Comment: when you can, pls 'accept' your own answer. thx